# Why else condition is needed in c++ for good coding practice even if we have nothing to write in there?

Tags: c++

I have seen else condition even if there is nothing inside it in many standard code documents. Why is that? Why should we use else even there is nothing to write in there as a good practice?

```
int a=1,b=2;
if(a)
{
    a=a+b;
}
else
{
    // Why we need this even there is nothing to write
}
```

Comment: You don't exactly need that `else`, though. Where did you get that idea from?

Comment: Then the standard documents you're reading are bad and should be burned. It's a bogus coding convention.

Comment: If you have read anywhere that it is a good practice, please mention the source.

Comment: Sorry. I cannot provide the actual source document since there is some privacy issue. Does bogus coding convention applies to every language( especially c++) ? Please prove some link where I can find this convention.

Comment: Bogus coding convention isn't actually a convention. When I say "the coding convention you're referring to is bogus." Bogus in this context is kind of similar to "Bad",  "senseless" or "harmful". I could've reworded my previous comment to : "The coding convention you're reading is bad and you should not take it as good style."

Comment: conventions are just conventions, often the only reason for them to exists is to make similar stuff look similar. If a group of programmers decide to make this rule their convention then the reason to write the empty `else` is only that convention nothing else. Though I agree that this is completely bogus...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code standards are not global, these vary with the group, organization or community. **Some people think it is more readable and maintainable this way**, some think otherwise.
In my opinion, it is one of those rules made up by people who have too much free time on their hands.
I mean just look at it

```
if(condition) { do something }
else { }
```

How is that even more readable and maintainable. It is just adding some extra trash code.
I think one should avoid such documents for the sake of code.

However, if you work with people who follow the same standards either convince them to drop this out of standards or just walk away slowly :)